# What is the purpose of the JWT and Middleware function in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Every time a protected url is called i check for req.user that is set up automatically by the JWT middleware.

Now I'm wondering:

1 - where does JWT tokens are stored when calling sign() ?

2 - do i have to verify() the token every time a protected url is called? if yes why?

3 - When i set a new token for an already signed user does the old token (if exists) gets deleted ? What if the expiration is not been set up or is 5 years for example?

4 - Why can't I set new tokens on same browser/app page ? I get invalid signature error if i register a new token but the token matches (i checked) It's like I can't signin more than 1 user on same browser**strong text**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code. We don't know what "*the JWT middleware*" is nor how you are calling `sign` or how you are setting a new token.

Comment: "*do i have to verify() the token every time a protected url is called?*" - yes, if you didn't verify every request, the url wouldn't be protected. HTTP is stateless and every request is independent from another.

Answer (score 1):

1. JWT tokens do not need to be stored anywhere really, although some might do
2. you protect routes for a given reason, therefore it is essential to verify that non-authorised requests do not go through.
3. this depends on how you engineered the auth system, normally all the JWT tokens upon generation need to be told when to expire
4. I do not quite understand the problem here, you need to offer us more details before expecting a solution

Comment: Tokens need to be stored but the responsibility is on the client side. On subsequent requests, the client sends the token along. Thats one of the major selling points of tokens. It makes the backend stateless or at least its one factor that plays a role in doing so.